# Raising User Control Event VB.NET and passing variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am delving into territory unfamiliar to me. I'm creating a User Control that I'd like to use across multiple forms. (thus reason for User Control). I am only familiar with VB.NET language. I've googled and I think I'm close to understanding, but I just can't figure this out. I've got multiple buttons on my User Control. When the "upload" button is pressed on my user control, I'd like it to run a Sub on my parent page called UploadFile(), which has one string parameter. I will have the UserControl on my page mulitple times like this:

```
 <uc1:UploadFile ID="UploadFile1" runat="server" />

 <uc1:UploadFile ID="UploadFile2" runat="server" />
```

In my code behind of the parent page, I'd like to execute this function on the Click event of the upload button within the user control. Where the unique parameters will then tell me what folders I will be uploading my file to. So that when user uploads a file within my first User Control on the page, it will run my Upload Sub on my parent page, take the parameter "a" and run my Sub that uploads my document and saves to database for files specific to "a" type. I will then tell the user control to change it's label to show that File A has been uploaded

```
 Sub something somethingUploadFile1_Click
      UploadFile("a")
 End Sub

 Sub something somethingUploadFile2_Click
      UploadFile("b")
 End Sub

 Sub UploadFile(ByVal myString as string)
       Select Case myString

          Case "a"
             If UploadFile1.FileUpload.HasFile Then
                 'run code to upload file

                 'display label
                 UploadFile1.lblReplaceMsg.Text = "File " & myString & " has been uploaded."
             End If

          Case "b"
            If UploadFile2.FileUpload.HasFile Then
                 'run code to upload file

                 'display label
                 UploadFile2.lblReplaceMsg.Text = "File " & myString & " has been uploaded."
             End If
       End Select
 End Sub
```

I know that in above code I'm supposed to be somehow referencing the button on my UserControl, but I'm not sure how to do it. I also know that Raising Events and Event Delegation are two major components of this, but again, I'm just not figuring it out. Can you please show me how to complete my code using the existing examples I provided?

Here is the complete code behind of my existing UserControl:

```
Public Class UploadFile
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click

End Sub


Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

End Sub


Public Property lblViewFile() As Label
    Get
        Return _lblViewFile
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Label)
        _lblViewFile = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property btnDelete() As ImageButton
    Get
        Return _btnDelete
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ImageButton)
        _btnDelete = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property pnlUpload() As Panel
    Get
        Return _pnlUpload
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Panel)
        _pnlUpload = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property FileUpload() As FileUpload
    Get
        Return _FileUpload
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As FileUpload)
        _FileUpload = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property btnUpload() As Button
    Get
        Return _btnUpload
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Button)
        _btnUpload = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property lblReplaceMsg() As Label
    Get
        Return _lblReplaceMsg
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Label)
        _lblReplaceMsg = value
    End Set
End Property


Private _lblViewFile As Label
Private _btnDelete As ImageButton
Private _pnlUpload As Panel
Private _FileUpload As FileUpload
Private _btnUpload As Button
Private _lblReplaceMsg As Label






 End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

[asp.net vb user control raising an event on the calling page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594608/asp-net-vb-user-control-raising-an-event-on-the-calling-page)

derive the arguments class you need from EventArgs according to your structure and data and use that.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I'm going to need a lot more help than that.